# react-data-grid setScrollLeft is not a function - fixed columns not working - custom row renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I am trying to implement fixed columns in my [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid).
I follow the [example](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/scripts/example03-fixed-cols.js) by adding `locked: true` but it doesn't work, so I also try to use a custom row rendered, like the [other example](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/scripts/example12-customRowRenderer.js).

I get `_this.refs[i].setScrollLeft is not a function` error. Trying the hacky comment on [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581035/react-data-grid-setscrollleft-dose-not-work-when-customized-row-renderer-being) also doesn't work for me (sorry not enought rep to comment!).

I also tried to [create a custom cell render class](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/596), but still no luck.
I also try to use `refs` the callback way instead:

```
class CellRenderer extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return <ReactDataGrid.Cell {...this.props}/>
  }
};

class RowRenderer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    idx: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  setScrollLeft = (scrollBy) => {
    // if you want freeze columns to work, you need to make sure you implement this as apass through
    this.row.setScrollLeft(scrollBy);
  };

  getRowStyle = () => {
    return {
      color: this.getRowBackground()
    };
  };

  getRowBackground = () => {
    return this.props.idx % 2 ?  'green' : 'blue';
  };

  render() {return (<div style={this.getRowStyle()}>
      <ReactDataGrid.Row 
        {...this.props}
        ref={r => { this.row = r; }}
        cellRenderer={CellRenderer}
      />
    </div>);
  }
};
```

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Trying many things, still no luck, but I've figured out that the `setScrollLeft` method is never passed down to the `Row` component, so maybe it is indeed a problem with refs and/or props passed.

Comment: what name did you gave to your ref before setting it to be a callback?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. `RowRenderer` is a stateful compnent so I thought using `ref={r => { this.row = r; }}` is enough so I can call `this.row.setScrollLeft(scrollBy);`, isn't that right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you meant by "fixed" columns, but if you want the size of the columns to be set by the software and not changed by the user, you can simply set resizable = false.  Setting locked = true on the columns has the effect of "freezing" the column so that when you scroll, that particular columns stays there, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: By fixed columns I mean that a few columns are fixed on the left side of the table when you scroll to the right. That's why I added the link to the repo, you can check the [example](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/fixed-cols).

Comment: @gkri  I added this feature (locked=true) to a react app yesterday and it worked fine.  We are using react 15.4.2, react-data-grid 2.0.16 and Chrome browser.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! shorty after i posted my question i switched to another grid. When i find some time to test this one again i'll update my question :)